# How to return multiple things from POJO class in java

Tags: java, pojo

I am able to get output using console output as below.

```
true
false
{2=s, 3=h ,..}
```

these are two Boolean and a hash map i want to return them so that whenever i hit the service it gets displayed on browser.
if i use return statement then i can return only one thing
How can i return this combination? Please explain with full class or example.

i used new POJO to get the returned value but i am so much confused on this.

```
package com.vishal;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class DiffResponse {

    private boolean l = false;
    private boolean c = false;

    public HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public DiffResponse setResponse(boolean l, boolean c,
        HashMap<Integer, String> hm) {
        this.l = l;
        this.c = c;
        this.hm = hm;

        return new DiffResponse();

    }}
```

This is service

```
@POST
@Path("/compare/id")

public void delt`enter code here`a() {

    String s1 = al.get(0);
    String s2 = al.get(1);

    String s = null;
    boolean l = false;
    boolean c = false;

    if (s1.length() == s2.length())
        l = true;
    al.clear();
    if (s1.equals(s2))
        c = true;
    al.clear();

    DiffResponse DF = new DiffResponse();

    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
    int minLength = Math.min(c1.length, c2.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {

        if (c1[i] == c2[i]) {
            continue;
        } else {

            s = Character.toString(c2[i]); DF.hm.put(i, s);

        }

    }
    al.clear();
    System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(DF.hm);
    DF.setResponse(l, c, DF.hm);  //this output to be displayed using return
    DF.hm.clear();}}
```

I want to know how to combine these three outputs .

Comment: I did not understand your question, you want to return multiple things from the same method ?

Comment: yes, three outputs at a time

Comment: Collect the return value of setResponse and add it as entity to your response. But be sure to make a deep copy of hm instead just a reference or clearing it will be reflected in your response object.

Comment: If I understand you, just build an instance of `DiffResponse` with the values you want to return and return this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no 'tuple type' where you can return multiple things.

2 ideas:

- return a class/an array that acts as a 'composite'
- pass a class / an array and return it via this parameter

The code could be e.g.

```
public MyReturnValue foo() {
    ...
    return new MyReturnValue(x,y,z)
}

public Object[] foo() {
    ...
    return new Object[] {x,y,z}
}

public void foo(MyReturnValue valueToSet) {
    ...
    valueToSet.setXYZ(x,y,z)
}

public void foo(Object[] valueToSet) {
    ...
    valueToSet.[0] = x;
    valueToSet.[1] = y;
    valueToSet.[2] = z;
}
```

Comment: note that the array way is unsexy as hell... id DEFINITLY go with proposal one!

Comment: whats the logic of response builder.(ok). .. something like tht , how we do use that for multiple response ?

Comment: sure. you can also use a builder pattern with that: `return  ResponseBuilder.setX(x).setY(y).setZ(z);`

Comment: Just tell me now that if i have two boolean values l and c then can i use below statement to return both ?
return Response.ok().entity(String.valueOf(l)).entity(String.valueOf(c)).build();